# jquery find div attribute smaller or higher

Tags: jquery, html, find, compare

i want to find all div attributed value matched smaller or higher numeric value.

its worked me only eq value=444 (example div[ref=444],[ref=333]....)

var $filteredData = $data.find('div[ref=444]' );

but i want to compare find <444 ( find div attribute value smaller <444) or >444 (find div attribute value higher >444) in all div attribute value

how can find or select all div attr value smaller or higher
thanks for all

Answer (score 3):

Yes, attributes are strings, there is no selector to treat them as numbers. You would have to parse and [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) manually:

```
$filteredData= $data.find('div').filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).attr('ref'), 10)<444;
});
```

(But what's `ref`? If this is HTML content, that's not a standard attribute. Avoid custom HTML attributes; if you must use them, use HTML5 [`data-`](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) attributes. But other methods, such as putting the information in a className, might be better, depending on what you're doing.)

Comment: bobince - Is the `parseInt` really needed?

Comment: @patrick: Indeed not, in this case: the comparison between `String` and `Number` has an implicit conversion of `String` to `Number`, so `parseInt` would only be needed if there was something else in the attribute value that caused the implicit cast to give `NaN`. For example if the value was `123a` or some other not-wholly-a-number value that `parseInt`'s more lenient parsing would allow. Really I just wanted to be explicit: although the case of comparing `String` against `Number` is defined to work, there are many other cases where using a string containing a number won't work as expected.

Comment: bobince - Explicit/safe is good. Thanks for the response. +1 :o)