# Using jQuery to select a range of elements based on index

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a set of divs that I want to select 6-10 for:

```
<div index=1>
<div index=2>
...
<div index=9>
<div index=10>
```

How do i use jQuery to select the divs where index is 6 - 10?

Comment: @ming select means??? select and do what ??

Comment: is `index` an attribute to your div?

Comment: @we can you class indentifier to select a group of elements

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059625/using-jquery-how-do-i-select-a-range-of-rows

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060985/jquery-find-div-attribute-smaller-or-higher

Comment: those previous answers are too complicated. the "slice" function in the answers this perfectly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the jQuery slice function

http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Answer (score 8):

try something like this...if you want to select those div's

`$('div').slice(6, 10)`

and if you want index of div then use....

```
$('#divId').index();
```

Answer (score 1):

If index is a attribute you can try "[nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)"

```
$("DIV[index=6]").nextUntil("DIV[index=10]")
      .css("background-color", "red");
```

Comment: this would actually be useful in a different context. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#6, #7, #8, #9, #10')
```

Only other way I can think of is a for loop and use the index to select them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
   for (var i=6,w;i<10;i++){
      w = $('').add('div[index='+i+']');
   }
```

Variable 'w' points to jquery set of items